# Rename columns through loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code :

```
import pandas as pd

stocks=['GOOG.O','FB.O']
def ratios(x):
    df=x[2].loc[[1,7,8,10],:]
    df=df.set_index(df.columns[0])
    df.index.names=['Fundam Data']
    df.rename(columns={1:'Company',3:'Sector'}, inplace=True)
    del df[2]
    return df

def results():
    dataframe=pd.DataFrame()
    for titulos in stocks:     
        ruta=pd.read_html('http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol='+str(titulos),flavor='html5lib')
        x=ratios(ruta)
        if dataframe.empty:
            dataframe= x
        else:
            dataframe=pd.concat([dataframe,x],axis=1, join_axes=dataframe.index)
    return dataframe    
print (results())
```

The current output is:

```
                         Company Sector Company Sector
Fundam Data
P/E Ratio (TTM)            32.14  20.94   43.25  20.94
Price to Sales (TTM)        7.01   5.62   15.71   5.62
Price to Book (MRQ)         4.60   1.98    7.34   1.98
Price to Cash Flow (TTM)   24.70  14.83   34.57  14.83
```

I would like to substitute the name 'Company' by the corresponding ticker.
The desired output would be:

```
                          GOOG.O Sector   FB.O  Sector
Fundam Data
P/E Ratio (TTM)            32.14  20.94   43.25  20.94
Price to Sales (TTM)        7.01   5.62   15.71   5.62
Price to Book (MRQ)         4.60   1.98    7.34   1.98
Price to Cash Flow (TTM)   24.70  14.83   34.57  14.83
```

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking for here. Could you add a table with the result output as you want it?

Comment: @Max Power , my apologize, edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ratios(x)` you manually set the column names to 'Company' with `df.rename(columns={1:'Company',3:'Sector'}, inplace=True)`. But then in results you loop through each specific company name with `for titulos in stocks`. My solution just passes the specific company name you're iterating through from `results()` to `ratios()` so it can be used in the rename statement.

This prints your desired results.

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib

stocks=['GOOG.O','FB.O']
def ratios(x, company_name):
    df=x[2].loc[[1,7,8,10],:]
    df=df.set_index(df.columns[0])
    df.index.names=['Fundam Data']
    df.rename(columns={1:company_name,3:'Sector'}, inplace=True)
    del df[2]
    return df

def results():
    dataframe=pd.DataFrame()
    for titulos in stocks:     
        ruta=pd.read_html('http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol='+str(titulos),flavor='html5lib')
        x=ratios(ruta, titulos)
        if dataframe.empty:
            dataframe= x
        else:
            dataframe=pd.concat([dataframe,x],axis=1)#, join_axes=dataframe.index])
    return dataframe    

print (results())
```